# Is it not possible to load two C# COM object built with different NETCore versions?

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, com

I have a legacy system written in **Delphi** that needs to consume COM objects built in **NETCore**. Everything was working fine while all COM assemblies were built with NET6. The problem began when I tried to load a new COM object written in NET7.
That is the error I get:

> The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.0', apply_patches=1, version_compatibility_range=minor is incompatible with the previously loaded version '7.0.1'.

In Delphi I'm using the **CreateComObject** function from **System.Win.ComObj** to get the COM.

In C# I'm using ComVisible(true), and I'm also generating a **MyCSharpCom.comhost.dll** and using **regsvr32** to registry it.

My question is: why is the load of one COM object sharing the same NET framework with the others ones?

Is it possible to fix that keeping the same architecture, since I cannot enforce the NET core version used by third parties who also write COM objects as a plugin/extension to be consumed by a Delphi exe?

Comment: Presumably not at least it was not automatically possible with the pre core frameworks. To get that running you would need to start the fitting NET Framework and the COM object manually in code. Those things where called a "shim" back in the days and maybe someone in the delphi community has written one.

Comment: I'm kinda lost here. I though COM objects would not interfere with each other, but looking into CreateComObject I noticed there are two flags CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER and CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtypesbase/ne-wtypesbase-clsctx
The doc says CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER means " The class code (in either case) will be run in a separate service process on the same computer as the caller." which should works, but I don't know how to force this mode.

Comment: You meant "looking into the registry" right? CreateComObject doesn't really fiddle with those flags. The COM object started here might have been registered with those flags previously and CreateComObject will create the object or a proxy to the external process according to the flags it finds in the registry concerning this COM type.

Comment: I meant "CreateComObject". That is the code to get a COM object in Delphi:

`CoCreateInstance(ClassID, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IUnknown, Result)`

I'm wondering it there is a way to force a COM object to run using CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER.

Comment: @dougcunha no, you can't force it. The COM object has to be implemented as an out-of-process server (ie, an `.exe`) in order to load it using `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER`. Likewise, the COM object has to implemented as an in-process server (ie, a `.dll`) in order to load it using `CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER`

Comment: @dougcunha the .NET framework is implemented as a series of shared DLLs, that is why multiple COM objects are able to interfere with each other when they are using different versions of .NET. I wonder if [activation contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/activation-contexts) can be used to solve this? That is one way to have multiple DLL versions loaded in the same process. But I don't know if that will work with .NET

Comment: @RemyLebeau when you say activation contexts are you referring to C# code or Delphi? I was looking into the possibility to make a DLL surrogate in C# and load it as local server in Delphi, but it seems there is no support for it in NET Core and I don't want to use NET Framework unless there is no other way.

Comment: @dougcunha activation contexts can be managed in code or via manifests. Read the link I provided in my earlier comment. In this case, I'm referring to the Delphi code when it is calling `CreateComObject()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau i don't think Activation Context helps. They isolate things in the runtime but here different runtimes need to be isolated from each other. Its not a problem of the runtime but of the host of the runtimes. For Net Framework there was a [subsystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/)  for hosting the runtime in unmanged code. Have used it with the classic frameworks but looks to me that it haven't made it into the core world. Atleast the docs end with Framework 4.

Comment: @Ralf looks like I have to try something different. Do you think that a new NET Framework ou Core DLL could load my COM objects? In this case, I would load this new DLL in Delphi and since this new DLL wouldn't have any dependency but NET Framework, It could work. I'll have a try.

Comment: Are you sure you want to move to .NET7 for a production app?  .NET6 is the Long-Term-Support version, .NET7 will be out of support first.  .NET8 will be the next Long-Term-Support version. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

Comment: @user700390 my company has a policy of always keeping the last NET version. We've been doing that since net3 and the advantages are higher then the disadvantages. NET7 introduced a lot of performance optimization and news features that it's worth the upgrade in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can only be a single instance of the .NET runtime loaded at a time in any given process. The load fails because you are using the COM classes in process and they try to load multiple instances of the .NET runtime to the same process.

You would need to use the COM classes out of process.

If the supplier of the COM classes is not able to give you out of process version of the COM class then you would need to create separate out of process COM server applications using .Net which would act as a proxy to the the in process COM classes. You may decide to only create a proxy for the .Net 7 COM classes, so .net 6 COM classes would be continued to used as it is but the .Net 7 would be used via the proxy out of process. Or you may create proxies for all classes, depending on your needs.

Here is an example how to create out of process COM class in .Net:
https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/main/core/extensions/OutOfProcCOM

Comment: is that approach the same as DLL surrogate?

Comment: in theory yes altough I was never able to make it work properly (too much magic happening). I have used the approach described above successfully

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as the correct one. As there is no way to load more than one NET framework version using a in-process COM server, I had to implement a out-of-process one by following the sample @rm provided.